# Enable dragging the volume slider in jPlayer (2.3.0)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jplayer

I'm using the jPlayer media library on my website to play some MP3 files. I'm currently using the Blue Monday theme (http://www.jplayer.org/latest/demo-01/?theme=0). I noticed that the volume slide won't work if you want to drag it to the left or right to decrease or increase the sound volume. Is there any way to enable the volume slider to be dragged to change the volume?

Answer (score 4):

I used: http://loopj.com/jquery-simple-slider/

Example: http://beta.kungfuvampire.com/v5/

Replace the volume divs with:

```
<input type="text" data-slider="true" value="1" data-slider-highlight="true">
```

Then bind to jplayer volume:

```
$("[data-slider]")
    .bind("slider:ready slider:changed", 
        function (event, data) {
                $(".jp-jplayer").jPlayer( "volume", data.value.toFixed(3));
    });
```

Hope that helps